# Battle of the Vectors

Tags: unity, efficiency

When building a Unity2d game, is it better to use Vector3's for waypoints, etc... or to use Vector2's ?

The advantage I can see of using a Vector2 is that it is smaller (2 floats vs. 3) and therefore more space efficient, However Unity is not really designed with 2d in mindd, therefore all object positions are stored as Vector3s.

Is the memory saved from usinng Vector2s instead of vector3s worth the amount of time the computer spendds converting Vector2s to vector3s and the reverse?

Comment: This would be more efficient because vectors are structs in unity api. That means that they are fully copied each time and can't be stored as a reference type (correct me if I'm wrong). So when you set a transform.position it creates new structure of vector3 anyway, with vector2 it just reads 1 value less and leaves it at default. But it's not worth your time bothering about it, you should understand the topic but don't care about it once you get it - if and only if you don't pass the threshold when it matters. For example, if you have 1000 objects on the map, it still wouldn't matter too much

Comment: Every time you create a new variable, you ask to give it memory space. This also takes some processing power, so sometimes it's even faster to match or check some values or convert. But it depends on the situation if it doesn't affect the gameplay and fps then don't bother about it. This is called micro optimization and it will prevent you from thinking about more important aspects of the game for the time being. You can start optimizing if it's the thing that is causing a problem.

Comment: What profiling have you done that points to this being an actual performance problem in your game?

Comment: @DmGregory, it was out of curiosity. To be honest. I decided to use vector3's only a little bit after I asked the question, because ease of programming. And I have not bothered optimizing yet because my code is not yet complete (why waste time optimizing when you don't know which code is the bottleneck?)

Comment: Just be cognisant that, if the optimization is so minor that you don't consider it worth your time to investigate, it might not be something you want to take up others' time with either. Users here are making a good-faith effort to help improve & answer questions. If you refrain from asking questions to which you don't actually need the answer, that effort can be focused on questions that do need answers.

Comment: That did not come out how I meant it to. .. what I meant was I do not know if optimization is important yet for where this is used,  but the code where this is could be ran 1000's of times ever 1/60 of a second and then not ar all at other times depending on the user. Also a pary of this question is if the time saved in allocation time (for storage) with the time didn't in converting one type to another.

Answer (score 0):

So, let's say a Vector2 occupies 8 bytes and a Vector3 occupies 12 (they don't, but this should make our lives easier). A typical "minimum requirement" computer has 4GB of RAM. Since mos of this place is occupied by textures, gameobjects and such, let's say you only use 0.5 GBs (this is still a very big chunk of memory relatively) to store your vectors. In this case you could theoretically store up to 67,108,864 Vector2s and 44,739,242. It's safe to say that you ran out of possibilities and time before running out of space (you'll still need to shovel all these information to the GPU to do anything useful with it).

When you look for ways to optimize your code before you encounter a performance bottleneck, then we call the premature optimization. It's usually a waste of time. Use a profiler when you need to optimize.